Snap applications can't see outside their container
I have a couple of applications installed via snap that I am having issues with, and it seems to be a containerization issue.

I installed the Vuze app, but when I click on a magnet link in Firefox, it will not be opened by vuse.  I'm not sure if this is a Firefox issue not knowing how to parse magnet links, or justthe snap version on Vuze not accepting outside links.

The JDownloader snap app cannot follow simlinks, or even access another mounted filesystem.


